# Why adding arguments to Celery causing error on tests in Python?

Tags: python, celery, python-mock

I'm trying to test Celery application here's my code

```
@celery.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30)
def convert_video(gif_url, webhook):
    // doing something awesome
       return
    except Exception as exc:
       raise convert_video.retry(exc=exc)
```

And in my test I have this.

```
server.convert_video.apply(args=('some_gif', 'http://www.company.com?attachment_id=123')).get()
```

After I added `bind=True, default_retry_delay=30` I get this error

> TypeError: convert_video() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: If this is supposed to be a method, it needs to declare a `self` argument.

Comment: but if I deleted `bind=True, default_retry_delay=30` it works fine.

Comment: and if you delete `bind=True`, or set `bind=False`, it will work fine as well.

Comment: You're right if `bind=False` it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I've never used celery, but a quick look at their [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context) for the `bind` argument says that:

> The bind argument means that the function will be a “bound method” so that you can access attributes and methods on the task type instance.

You generally would only use this if this were a method on a class, not a stand-alone function.  As a method on a class, its first argument would be `self`.

Answer (score 1):

you're using the `bind` parmater which means that the first paramater passed to the function will be the task instance - it effectively makes the function a method of the `Task` class.

```
@celery.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30)
def convert_video(self, gif_url, webhook):
    try:
        log.info('here we have access to task metadata like id: %s', self.request.id)
        return
    except Exception as exc:
        raise convert_video.retry(exc=exc)
```